# switching with transistor

Tags: arduino, power, voltage

I want to feed the load by 1.2V source. I want to control it by a voltage changes between 0 to 2 V. I want the switch be closed and feed the load if control voltage is lower than 0.2V and switch be open if the control voltage is above 0.2V. I have used a bc557. connect the 1.2V source to emitter and 0-2V to base. However, the switch operate when base voltage become 0.5V. Is there anyway to change this 0.5V to 0.2?

Comment: What power supply voltage do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

As the BC557 is a PNP according to your figures you have 1.2 - 0.5V (= 0.7V) across the base-emitter junction at turn on which sounds correct.

You could try adding a schottky diode (anode to base of bc557) to increase the 'base - emitter' drop and reduce the value of the 'turn on' voltage. This will not give you a precise turn on but it will get you closer to your 0.2V.

[image]

The forward drop of a schottky diode is about 0.2V. You could also experiment with a couple of germanium diodes (about 0.17V each) or even try a silicon diode (~ 0.65V).

Comment: You should note that the load will see a little less than 1.2 V due to the C-E drop of the transistor when on.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm fully aware of the C-E drop and that the solution proposed is not particularly accurate However, I was taking the circuit that was described in the question and showing how it could be simply modified rather than proposing a totally different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the venerable [LM10](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm10.pdf), which will happily operate from 1.2V and contains an accurate voltage reference (it happens to be 200mV, so you can use it directly) and an op-amp which can be used as a comparator.

[image]

A BJT can be switched by the op-amp/comparator output as few MOSFETs are guaranteed to work well with 1.2V Vgs. However, one such MOSFET is the [AON2400](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AON2400.pdf) an 8V/8A part which has only 23m\$\Omega\$ Rds(on) with 1.2V drive.

Answer (score 1):

For such a low threshold voltage, you will need to use a comparator.  Here is the basic scheme:

[image]

You didn't say what power supplies are available, so I'm assuming something like 5 V is there or you can make it.  If the whole thing has to run from only 1.2 V, it will be more difficult.  You're not going to find something that can do what you want while running from 1.2 V natively.  You would then have to use a switcher to make something like 5 V to run the comparator from.